# error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

Tags: c++, qt, build, c-preprocessor

Just a Qt Gui Application with QDialog as the Base Class, the simplest type you can expect.
I've programmed on Qt for several times but this is the first time I meet this problem...
I've added minimal code to the program, and here's the code in dialog.h (which is mostly automatically generated)

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QPixmap>
#include "bmp.h"

namespace Ui {
    class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_openButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    BMP srcImage;
    QImage compressedImage[3];
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

While I edit, the "public:" is underlined and says "unexpected token '('". When I try to build the program, it says in the line "Q_OBJECT", "error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant". I'm sure I've defined nothing related to it (to be exact, I defined an N and an n in file bmp.h, both are int).

Any idea of what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you running it through moc first?

Comment: I've no idea what "moc" is...so maybe no?

Comment: moc is the Qt preprocessor that makes the signal/slot mechanism work.  The code has to be run through moc to turn it into valid C++ code.  qmake will do this for you if it is set up properly:  http://doc.trolltech.com/4.0/moc.html

Comment: The thing is that I wrote several QT programs before, they worked out fine and this problem never occurred...I don't think I've done anything special this time

Comment: Try to right-click on the project, then do "Clean Project", then "Run Qmake" and "Rebuild project".

Comment: You may not have had problems before because you didn't make any direct calls to slot/slot mechanisms or didn't define any yourself.  *Sometimes* you don't absolutely need to run it through the MOC, even when you inherit from classes that do.

Comment: Vaughn Cato: No. The header above is perfectly valid C++ code. moc does generate /additional/ code, whose absence isn't noticed until link time.

Comment: goldfrapp04: Check your bmp.h for #define's that collide with any keyword or identifiers above. Also check the preprocessor output (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493293/preprocessor-output-on-qt-creator/4493611#4493611)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured it out myself.
I included some

```
#pragma pack(push)
#pragma pack(1)
//...
#pragma pack(pop)
```

in file "bmp.h". When I move the line

```
#include "bmp.h"
```

into file "dialog.cpp", everything works well